# Linear dynamics in a function space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, ds.dynamical-systems

I posted the same question to Math Stackexchange earlier without much luck, so I am posting here.

I am dealing with a time-dependent model, which can be expressed as a function. $f$ is dependent on two variables: $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (an input to the model),and $t\in \mathbb{R}$ (time). Although the function is dependent on both variables, I will use the following notation $f(x):=f(x,t)$ where the dependency to and $t$ is implied. $f : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

Consider a function $\Pi: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$:

$$ \Pi (f) (x) = \sum_{i=1}^{P} K \left(x,x_i\right) f(x_i) $$

where $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$, and $K:\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. To clarify, $\Pi (f) (x)$ means "evaluate $\Pi (f) \in \mathcal{F}$ at $x$". The set $\{x_1,\ldots,x_P\}$ is fixed (not time-dependent), but the input $x$ to the function $K \left(x,x_i\right)$ can be any value in $\mathbb{R}^d$. $K$ is a symmetric tensor in $\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{F}$. (side note: In fact, $K_{kk'}(x,x')=\mathbb{E}_g[g_k(x)g_{k'}(x')]$, where $g_k(x)$ indicates $k^{th}$ coordinate of $g(x)$. $g$ is a function that is randomly sampled from $\mathcal{F}$ according to some distribution. The sampling/averaging has nothing to do with the time $t$. Also, $K$ does not change over time $t$. Equivalently, $g$ is independent of $t$.)

Our dynamical equation for a function $f$ is:

$$ \frac{\partial f_t}{\partial t}=\Pi(f_t) $$

Apparently, assuming $f_0$ as the initial condition, the solution is

$$ f_t = \exp(t\Pi) f_0$$

but I am not sure how to prove this. The solution for a matrix differential equation has the same form and I can prove it for that, but I am not sure how to do it for this functional case.

To provide the context, this is from the neural tangent kernel paper by Jacot et al.

Comment: This is standard result in linear PDE theory. E.g., the solution of heat equation $\partial_tf(x,t)=\Delta f(x,t)$  is $e^{\Delta t}f(x,0)$. Numerous proofs...you can start by reading up Green's functions

Comment: @PiyushGrover: This is not a PDE though. It's an ODE for the quantities $f(x_i)$, and once we have solved this, we find $f(x)$ for $x\not= x_i$ simply by integration. This seems a rather strange structure, so maybe the OP can clarify if this is really what was meant.

Comment: @ChristianRemling In my case, $f$ is a function of both $x$ and $t$; I should have been clear. The quantities $f(x_i)$ change over time according to the ODE. So yes, I can solve matrix differential equation to solve for the value of $f(x_i)$ at time $t$. However, I am not sure how exactly to arrive at the “functional” exponential equation that I wrote in the post.

Comment: @CWC: Thank you for clarifying. I don't think your question can be meaningfully answered without those details about the $x_j(t)$ you just referred to, so maybe it would be a good idea to edit your question along these lines.

Comment: And while you edit can you please also clarify the following: (i) are the $x_i$, $i=1,\ldots,P$ fixed, could we not simply write $\sum K_i(x) f(x_i)$? what are your assumption on the functions in $\mathcal{F}$? What assumption on $K$ ensures that $\Pi$ maps from $\mathcal{F}$ to $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: Thank you @ChristianRemling I edited the post to provide more details. $x$ is independent of $t$, and $f$ is explicitly dependent on $t$.

Comment: Thank you @FabianWirth I edited the post to provide more details. Yes, $x_i$ are fixed. Yes, writing as $\sum_i K_i(x)f(x_i)$ works too, assuming $x_i$ are implied in $K_i$.

Comment: But now my first comment applies: if we relabel $K(x_i,x_j)=c_{ij}$, then this is a linear homogeneous ODE with constant coefficients for the $P$ functions $y_i(t)=f(x_i,t)$, which we can indeed solve as $y=e^{tC}y(0)$ by standard ODE theory.

Comment: @ChristianRemling yes, I agree that $f(x_i,t)$ for $i=1,\ldots,P$ evolves as a linear homogeneous ODE and therefore agree with $y=e^{tC}y(0)$. However, I am not sure how this generalizes to $f(x,t)$ for $x$ that is not in ${x_i}$. In the first comment, you mentioned we can find it by integration, but I am not sure what that means.. More precisely, I am not sure how to arrive at the following expression that I have in my post: $f(x,t)=e^{t\Pi}(f_0)$.

Comment: I think my issue is mainly with the notation. I am not sure what it means to take an exponential of linear operator $t\Pi$. If I treat it like a matrix exponential, then I get a series, but then I am not sure what it means by $\Pi^2$, $\Pi^3$, $\Pi^4$, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure either what the exponential notation is supposed to mean for $x\not= x_i$, but the issue itself is straightforward: for such $x$ (and let's write $y(t)=f(x,t)$ again), the equation is $y'=g(t)$, with $g(t)=\sum K(x, x_j) f(x_j,t)$ (assuming we have solved the equations for $f(x_j,t)$ already, as discussed above), so $y(t)=y(0)+\int_0^t g(s)\, ds$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Ah I see, the computation is logically very clear. Thank you. I guess I will need to ask the author of the paper regarding the notation.